# Throttling duplicate requests

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looking at a way to throttle duplicate requests within a HttpModule. Unfortunately I keep getting the following error: I'm looking for a solution with an explanation also please.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: The semaphore has been disposed.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException: The semaphore has been disposed.
>   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.CheckDispose()
>   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release(Int32 releaseCount)
>   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release()

My approach is as follows.

```
// Container for semaphores
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> 
SemaphoreSlims = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();

// Wrapper for getting semaphore
private static SemaphoreSlim GetSemaphoreSlim(string id)
{
    return SemaphoreSlims.GetOrAdd(id, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
}


private async Task ProcessImageAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    // `hash` is the request path hashed.
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = GetSemaphoreSlim(hash);
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();

    try
    {

    // Do awaitable task

    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

`Dispose()` is only called (by me) during the disposal of the httpModule itself.

```cs
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.isDisposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (disposing)
    {
        // Dispose of any managed resources here.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SemaphoreSlim> semaphore in SemaphoreSlims)
        {
            semaphore.Value.Dispose();
        }

        SemaphoreSlims.Clear();
    }

    // Call the appropriate methods to clean up
    // unmanaged resources here.
    // Note disposing is done.
    this.isDisposed = true;
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint to see how even your dispose code was called and by whom.

Comment: I'd have to log it somehow. The error throwing seems to only happen under load and sporadically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apparently, both HttpApplication and HttpModule's are instantiated multiple times.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1107307.aspx?Whether%20the%20Init%20method%20of%20HttpModule%20only%20happen%20one%20time%20in%20all%20life%20cycle%20) (This design looks very questionable to me. In other words, a design flaw in ASP.NET. Those instances should just be singletons like everybody expects them to be.)

The static dictionary is being processed by multiple instances being disposed.

You don't need to dispose at all. Just let the OS delete those resources when the worker process dies.

Not, that your dictionary will grow without bounds.

Also, the semaphore instance you pass to GetOrAdd will almost always leak without being disposed.

Comment: Interesting thanks. Could you demo a better pattern?

Comment: Just delete the dispose code. You want to keep the data for the duration the app is running, so don't ever destroy it. If you insist, you could keep a ref count of active module instances using Interlocked.Inc/Dec. That's going to be hard to get right, though.

Comment: Ah right, thanks...

Doing some quick memory usage tests it's ~156 megabytes for 1 million items stored in the dictionary. I think that's reasonable but obviously I'd like to keep it to the bare minimum. I'll have a look at Interlocked but I may just leave it.

Comment: My recommendation: Delete the dispose code and clear the dictionary every night an 4:00 so that it does not grow without bounds. Very simple solution.

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate that possibility.